# How to delete duplicate rows from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I read a few other posts about how to delete duplicate records without a primary key but they delete all the records that are duplicated this is what I have tried

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column IN
( 
select column from
(
    SELECT    MAX(column )as column FROM table
    GROUP BY column 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2)as table
)
```

Is it because I only have one column in my table?

If I cant delete them all is there a way to just copy all the distinct records to another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query fails because of a limitation in MySQL.  Just rephrase it as a `join`.  Here is one way:

```
DELETE t
    FROM table t LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(column ) as column
     FROM table
     GROUP BY column
    ) tosave
    ON t.column = tosave.column
WHERE tosave.column is null;
```

EDIT:

Oops.  I was following the structure of your query.  That isn't going to work with one column.  You are going to need to do this with a temporary table and re-insert:

```
create temporary table temptable as
    select distinct column
    from tablename;

truncate table tablename;

insert into tablename(column)
    select column
    from temptable;
```

Comment: what does "t" stand for? and im a little confused exactly what you code does im in my first year of study so im still a noob.

Comment: `t` is a table alias.  You should understand what that is, it is an important part of the language.

Comment: Thank you i havnt implemented your code yet because i have 300, 000 records  and i want to trial it first will it be a problem if i have that many rows?

Comment: @user3991643 . . . That is probably not too many rows.  Any time you are deleting lots of rows, you have to deal with logging issues that take a bit of time.

Comment: Thanks mate you've been a great source of knowledge. I know were not meant to say thank you but if your going to take the time to help me the least i can do is like and say thanks

Comment: Hey mate just tried to implement your code but it doesnt do anything just displays the rows in the table

Comment: A `delete` displays rows in the table?  `delete`s don't display anything.

Comment: Are you using "temporary" as a reserved keyword or as the new table because either way its tell me im getting a syntax error

Comment: @user3991643 . . . `temporary` is definitely part of the `create table` syntax in MySQL:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one column, selecting duplicates becomes impossible, because SQL is based on set-logic.

Selecting distinct values is very simple: `select distinct column from table`. Inserting this into a table is also easy: `select * into newtable from (select distinct column from table)`